# How can I debug a Fortran READ/WRITE statement with an implicit DO loop?

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

The Fortran program I am working is encountering a runtime error when processing an input file.

```
At line 182 of file ../SOURCE_FILE.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'INPUT_FILE.1')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read
```

Looking to line 182 I see a READ statement with an implicit/implied DO loop:

```
182:    READ(IT4, 310 )((IPPRM2(IP,I),IP=1,NP),I=1,16)    ! read 6 integers
183:    READ(IT4, 320 )((PPARM2(IP,I),IP=1,NP),I=1,14)    ! read 5 reals
```

Format statement:

```
310 FORMAT(1X,6I12)
```

When I reach this code in the debugger `NP` has a value of 2. `I` has a value of 6, and `IP` has a value of 67. I think `I` and `IP` should be reinitialized in the loop.

My problem is that when I try to step through in the debugger once I get to the READ statement it seems to execute and then throw the error. I'm not sure how to follow it as it reads. I tried stepping into the function, but it seems like that may be a difficult route to take since I am unfamiliar with the gfortran library. The input file looks OK, I think it should be read just fine. This makes me think this READ statement isn't looping as intended.

I am completely new to Fortran and implicit DO loops like this, but from what I can gather line 182 should read in 6 integers according to the format string #310. However, when I arrive `NP` has a value of 2 which makes me think it will only try to read 2 integers 16 times.

How can I debug this read statement to examine the values read into `IPPARM` as they are read from the file? Will I have to step through the Fortran library?

Any tips that can clear up my confusion regarding these implicit loops would be appreciated!

Thanks!

NOTE: I'm using gfortran/gcc and gdb on Linux.

Comment: I think it's reading 16*NP integers, probably 6 per line although I've never tried implied do loops with a formatted file...

Answer (score 1):

The variables IP and I are loop indices and so they are reinitialized by the loop.  With NP=2 the first statement is going to read a total of 32 integers -- it is contributing to the determination the list of items to read.   The format determines how they are read.  With `"1X,6I12"` they will be read as 6 integers per line of the input file.  When the first 6 of the requested 32 integers is read fron a line/record, Fortran will consider that line/record completed and advance to the next record.

With a format of `"1X,6I12"` the integers must be precisely arranged in the file.  There should be a single blank, then the integers should each be right-justified in fields of 12 columns. If they get out of alignment you could get the wrong value read or a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you need specific formatting on the read? I would use READ(IT4, *) where feasible...

Later versions of gfortran support unlimited format reads (see link http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status)

Then it may be helpful to specify

```
310 FORMAT("*(1X,6I12)")
```

Or for older compilers

```
310 FORMAT(1000(1X,6I12))
```

Comment: These formats will read all the numbers from the same line, but need an extra space every six.  (*I12) or (1000I12) would probably be more convenient.  The suggestion to use list-directed I/O, READ (IT4, *), is by the easiest.