# Read specified number on reals on line

Tags: fortran77

I'm writing a program in Fortran 77 and I need to read a specified number of REAL numbers on one line. For example, the input may look like the following:

1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0

The number of values on one line will be specified. This will be held in some value, called M.

How do I read M REAL values on one line. I've tried doing this with a loop, but I believe the READ statement skips to the next line after it executes. Also, I'm using the VARIABLE INFILE to reference the file unit.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523763/how-can-i-debug-a-fortran-read-write-statement-with-an-implicit-do-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `READ` to read in a whole array of specified length. Here is an example:

```
         PROGRAM READRL
         PARAMETER (SIZELM=100)
         DIMENSION RLIST(SIZELM)
  C      Define your M here. 
         M = 3
  C      Read the M values into the first M positions of RLIST.
         CALL RDNMRS(M,RLIST)
         END PROGRAM READ

         SUBROUTINE RDNMRS(M, RLIST)
         DIMENSION RLIST(M)
         READ(*,*) RLIST
         END SUBROUTINE RDNMRS
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable as real array of size suitable to your problem. The array name is `VAR1` and its size is `100`. You can make it of any size.

```
REAL VAR1(100)
....................
READ(INFILE,*)(VAR1(I),I=1,M)
...................
```

Hope it works for you.